# count no of character occurance in .csv file column and display in graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I an trying to build graph using `d3.js`

Here what I need to do is to read the `some_column` column in `.csv` file and count no. of occurances of `|` and them accordingly on y axis. 
The line should be plotted with no of their occurences

Ex. If `some_column` values are like "value1||||", "val||2", "value3|" it should count `|` tags and value will become 4,2,1 and place them accordingly as their count comes.

I have defined a function

```
function parseColumn(tagnname)
{
var count = tagname.split("|").length - 1; 
return count;
}
```

but unable to display its returned value on Y-axis and plot the line according to these values.

[the code which I tried](http://plnkr.co/edit/8QkDuJIMlO4uXT2c5cvr?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are just a few small problems. First, you have a typo in the argument name to the `parseHashtags` function (`tagnname`). Second, you need to use the parsed value to determine the max of the y domain instead of parsing again.

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/prEIfTba3pQU8VoUc316?p=preview).

Comment: but why date is not coming correctly? Its just showing the time. `12:31` this value isn't anywhere in the `created_at` column

Comment: I'm guessing that your timezone is GMT+5. The times in the CSV are given in GMT, but will be displayed in local time. If you want a UTC scale, use `d3.time.scale.utc()`.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Lars. You are a savior :)